# Get data from dropbox

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I have a imgslider that select and imgs from my webhost(FTP) and want to edit so the that the img slider get the imgs from my dropbox folder, but i dont know how to do it.

Now i just use a is_dir_empty($dir), and maybe i can use the just add so i have access to my dropboxfolders. Idont know.

Does anyone knows how to use the dropbox api to check if dropbox-dir is empty and then get and loop them in into my website.

```
 $dir = "img/uploads/"; 

 if (!is_dir_empty($dir)) {
     $filesfound = true;
     $filetype = "img";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with https://www.dropbox.com/developers to learn about the API. Specifically, you'll probably use [`/metadata`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) to list the images and [`/media`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media) to get URLs for each.